# Calculate number and define dates of the weeks (incomplete and complete) in a timespan

Tags: vb.net, date, logic

I need to find **a) the number of total weeks** but also **b) the starting/ending dates (Monday, Sunday)** for each week in the timespan (fromDate,toDate) in the following manner:

```
fromDate: Thursday, 9/1/2016
toDate: Friday, 10/14/2016
----------------------------------------------------
Week1: Thursday, 9/1/2016 - Sunday, 9/4/2016
Week2: Monday, 9/5/2016 - Sunday, 9/11/2016
Week3: Monday, 9/12/2016 - Sunday, 9/18/2016
Week4: Monday, 9/19/2016 - Sunday, 9/25/2016
Week5: Monday, 9/26/2016 - Sunday, 10/2/2016
Week6: Monday, 10/3/2016 - Sunday, 10/9/2016
Week7: Monday, 10/10/2016 - Friday, 10/14/2016
```

So i need also to populate in a formal, calendar like manner the **incomplete weeks at the begging and at the end of the timespan** (fromDate, toDate)

I have implemented a logic in VB but i am missing the LAST week in some cases where the toDate day is: Monday and Tuesday. So, some parameter or the exact logic is not 100% right. Code below:

```
Public Shared Function GetWeeksFromTimespan(ByVal fromDate As Date, ByVal toDate As Date) As List(Of WeeksFromTimespan)

    Dim ListOfWeekTimespans As List(Of WeeksFromTimespan) = New List(Of WeeksFromTimespan)
    ' WeeksFromTimespan structure: WeekNumber As String, WeekNumber As Integer, fromDateWeek As Date, toDateWeek As Date
    ' fromDateWeek: week start date
    ' toDateWeek: week end date

    Dim Span As TimeSpan = toDate.Subtract(fromDate)

    Dim WeekCount As Integer = 0
    Dim Days As Integer = 0
    Dim DayCount As Integer = 0

    If Span.Days <= 7 Then

        If fromDate.DayOfWeek > toDate.DayOfWeek Then

            WeekCount = 2

            Dim DaysUntilEndOfFWeek As Integer = 0
            DaysUntilEndOfFWeek = 7 - fromDate.DayOfWeek

            Dim firstWeekEndDate As Date = fromDate.AddDays(DaysUntilEndOfFWeek)
            ListOfWeekTimespans.Add(New WeeksFromTimespan("Week1",1,fromDate,firstWeekEndDate))

            Dim secondWeekStartDate As Date = firstWeekEndDate.AddDays(1)
            ListOfWeekTimespans.Add(New WeeksFromTimespan("Week2",2,secondWeekStartDate,toDate))

        Else

            WeekCount = 1
            ListOfWeekTimespans.Add(New WeeksFromTimespan("Week1",1,fromDate,toDate))

        End If

    Else

        Days = Span.Days - 7 + CInt(fromDate.DayOfWeek)
        WeekCount = 1
        DayCount = 0

        Dim DaysUntilEndOfFWeek As Integer = 0
        DaysUntilEndOfFWeek = 7 - fromDate.DayOfWeek

        While DayCount <= Days

            If(DaysUntilEndOfFWeek>0) Then

                ListOfWeekTimespans.Add(New WeeksFromTimespan("Week" + WeekCount.ToString,WeekCount,fromDate.AddDays(DayCount),fromDate.AddDays(DaysUntilEndOfFWeek)))
                DayCount += DaysUntilEndOfFWeek+1
                WeekCount += 1
                DaysUntilEndOfFWeek = 0

            Else

                If(fromDate.AddDays(DayCount+6)<=toDate) Then
                    ListOfWeekTimespans.Add(New WeeksFromTimespan("Week" + WeekCount.ToString,WeekCount,fromDate.AddDays(DayCount),fromDate.AddDays(DayCount+6)))
                Else
                    ListOfWeekTimespans.Add(New WeeksFromTimespan("Week" + WeekCount.ToString,WeekCount,fromDate.AddDays(DayCount),toDate))
                End If

                DayCount += 7
                WeekCount += 1

            End If

        End While

    End If

    return ListOfWeekTimespans

End Function
```

However the code above does not populate the last INCOMPLETE WEEK when the last date (toDate) is on Monday, Tuesday. For example:

```
fromDate: 1/9/2016 (Thursday)
toDate: 11/10/2015 (Tuesday)
-----------------------------------------------
Week1: Thursday, 9/1/2016 - Sunday, 9/4/2016
Week2: Monday, 9/5/2016 - Sunday, 9/11/2016
Week3: Monday, 9/12/2016 - Sunday, 9/18/2016
Week4: Monday, 9/19/2016 - Sunday, 9/25/2016
Week5: Monday, 9/26/2016 - Sunday, 10/2/2016
Week6: Monday, 10/3/2016 - Sunday, 10/9/2016
```

So with the code above, i am missing the last incomplete week:

```
Week7: Monday, 10/10/2016 - Tuesday, 11/10/2015.
```

Need to refine this implementation for being able to accurately calculate the exam number and dates of "clear" weeks between two dates.

Comment: @Pikoh What was the point of that edit?

Comment: @DavidG the commented lines made all the code look a comment

Comment: You need to add 7 days to following statement :  Days = Span.Days - 7 + CInt(fromDate.DayOfWeek).  The While loop is terminating early.

Comment: @Pikoh No, you need to remove the C# tag so the system can figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: Tagged C# removed

Comment: Hmm,didn't know that @DavidG. Now I know for the next time, thanks

Comment: @Pikoh this may be useful too, if you cannot remove the tag, you can force the language syntax: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints

Comment: Note that [`DayOfWeek`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/dayofweek.cs,fe3a0e5f847fa6f8) values go from `Sunday = 0` to `Saturday = 6`.

Comment: @DavidG You always learn something new. Thank you again :)